# Facebook Connect in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, facebook

Is there a good way to get Facebook Connect onto a Silverlight page? All I really need is simple authorization/registration. I've looked into [the facebook developer toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/), but the documentation is more or less non-existent for Silverlight, and I didn't really get anywhere with it.

Is there a good tutorial or a working library for adding Facebook Connect into a Silverlight app? Or is the best way to run Silverlight in Windowwless mode with HTML overlayed on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use the WebBrowser control that was added in Silverlight 4 to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that? http://apps.facebook.com/chatmotion/

Before developing this small test app i took a look at these samples: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/39727

Make sure to download the newest source code of the Facebook Development Kit for .NET and build it yourself since the release version(January) didn't work for me correctly.

Let me know if you have any problems.